# Update Class \ Variable before submitting to STRIPE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, stripe-payments

I'm trying to customize my form with Stripe. After a user completes a form registration wizard, it will post the data to my PHP file that will insert the data into a MySQL database. After successful completion, the user will be redirected to an overview form detailing all the entered information. The user will then be able to enter their credit card information.

I'm using Stripe to validate the identity of the user by address, zipcode city and state. If the user's attempt to pay does not go through (as a result of a typo in their name, for example) he/she will be able to change it on the spot using AJAX. The AJAX will instantly update the record of the user.

When the user tries to submit the credit card information again by entering all the values, I would like the script that is already loaded to change to the new value that the user changed. Find below all my information. Thanks in advance and I really hope someone can help me.

Pre-loaded script:

```html
<!-- Create Token with Stripe -->
<script type="text/javascript">

// this identifies your website in the createToken call below
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_y4JUdKfi5hS4Vw7u1AnEfbeS');
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    if (response.error) {
        // re-enable the submit button
        $('.submit-button').removeAttr("disabled");
        // show the errors on the form
        $(".payment-errors").html(response.error.message);
    } else {
        var form$ = $("#payment-form");
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response['id'];
        // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "' />");
        // and submit
        form$.get(0).submit();
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#payment-form").submit(function(event) {
        // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $('.submit-button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        // createToken returns immediately,
        // the supplied callback submits the form if there are no errors
        Stripe.createToken({
            number: $('.card-number').val(),
            cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
            exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
            exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val(),
            name: $('.card-holder-name').val(),
            address_line1: $('.address').val(),
            address_city: $('.city').val(),
            address_zip: $('.zip').val(),
            address_state: $('.state').val()
        }, stripeResponseHandler);
        return false; // submit from callback
    });
});

</script> 

<!-- STRIPE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

(This is my form tag using AJAX to show and update)

```php
<a href="#" id="address"
    data-type="text"
    data-pk="1"
    data-name="from_street"
    data-params="<?php echo $current_account["email_id"];?>"data url="assets/php/editacct.php"
    data-original-title="Enter current address"
><?php echo $current_account["from_street"];?></a>
<script type="text/javascript">$('#address').editable();</script>
```

I am using [bootstrap-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/) to update the information.

How can I change the value of the address, zip, state and city before Stripe scripts creates the token?

Comment: write your code above `Stripe.createToken()`?

Comment: Can you be more specific please ?

Comment: Hi Leon, I don't see your comment. Do you have any advice ?